# Do concepts of effect size, power, and power analysis still make sense in the Bayesian framework?

Tags: statistics, bayesian, power-analysis

I do experiments on human language comprehension and encountered the question of sample size, effect size, and power analysis while designing my studies. At the same time, I ran Bayesian statistic models using `brms` in R. My question is, do the concepts of "Type I error", "Type II error", "alpha level", and the framework of running power analysis still make sense in the Bayesian framework? To me, the answer could be possible if we assume incompatibility of the frequentists' and Bayesian systems.